# How do I get the index of an element clicked using a plugin method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, slick.js

I am using the Slick JS slider and I am trying to grab the index of the slide clicked. All the attributes are available to me with a method called `'getSlick'`

The following code is logging all the indexes whenever a slide is clicked. I only want the index of the slide clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
  $('.sy-images-slides-primary .slick-slide').click(function(){
    console.log($(".sy-images-slides-primary").slick("getSlick").$slides);
  });
```

```js
// // define inner slider
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 110,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: true
});

  $('.slider .slick-slide').click(function () {
    $(".slider").slick("getSlick").$slides.each(function (index, slide) {
      console.log(index);
    });
  });
```

```css
.slick-slide {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this just after a slide was clicked use the plugin event "afterChange" instead of an extra click listener as you do.

```
$('.your-element').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
   //
});
```

Where the currentSlide is the index of the last slided element.

If you need an listener for a click on the slide itself you could read out the position from the data-attribute (you would have to normalize this value since there is also a -1 but this should easily work).

Your changed code:

```js
// // define inner slider
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 5,
  slidesToScroll: 5,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: 110,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  variableWidth: true
});

$('.slider').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide) {
  console.log('afterChange, currentSlide: ', currentSlide);
});
$('.slick-slide').on('click', function(ev){
  console.log('onClick slick-index:', $(ev.currentTarget).data('slick-index'));
});
```

```css
.slick-slide {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. If if does can you copy my code above and resolve it that way?

Comment: i just edited my answer... please use the callback or event of slick to get the event instead of an extra "click" listener

Comment: When I put that code above inside the afterChange event, it gives me an error: $(...).slick.$slides is not a function

Comment: see my example code of your implementation, im my updated answer, does this help?

Comment: Thanks this helped! do you know if theres a way to do it with my version using the onclick?

Comment: with the onclick you could just check which slider entry has the corresponding `slick-active` class

Comment: The problem is that I am trying to use the index clicked to set another thing. This isn't working for me since when you click the left and right arrow - it triggers the other event. That's why im using the onclick

Comment: so you only want an event when you click the element itself... and you need the index of this clicked element?

You can use the event object of an click event listener to receive the actual clicked element "currentTarget", there you can read out the `data-slick-index` attribute which contains the intex of the slider